# why looping speed differs a lot using different looping methods (Python)?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am doing online judgement for [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/) in Leetcode using Python.
I have written two solutions and they are almost the same.

It is so wired that solution 1 figures out the answer in a quite short time while solution 2 spends a long time. Both of them can result in a correct answer. The only difference is the method of looping. Therefore, then I use a variable “count” to calculate the times of looping. **It shows that the looping times of these two methods are almost the same.** Could you please give me any explanations?

The test case I used is from leetcode:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

My codes are as follows.

Solution 1:

```
class Solution(object):
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
    #:type s: str
   # :rtype: int
    maxLen = 0 if len(s) == 0 else 1
    i = 0
    j = 0
    aset = set()
    # count is used for counting times of looping
    count = 0
    while i < len(s) and j < len(s):
            count = count + 1
            if s[j] in aset:
                aset.remove(s[i])
                i = i+1
            else:
                aset.add(s[j])
                j = j+1
                maxLen = maxLen if j-i < maxLen else j-i
    print count,"loops"
    return maxLen
```

Solution 2:

```
class Solution(object):
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
    n = len(s)
    # count is used for counting times of looping
    count = 0
    maxLen = 0 if n == 0 else 1
    temp_j = 0
    aset = set()
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(temp_j,n):
            count = count + 1
            if s[j] in aset:
                aset.remove(s[i])
                temp_j = j
                break
            else:
                aset.add(s[j])
                temp_j = j
                maxLen = maxLen if j-i+1 < maxLen else j-i+1
    print count,"loops"
    return maxLen
```

Comment: The second take significantly longer because you're using `range()` in the for loops.  In Python 2 (which you appear to be using), `range()` builds a list, so it's got to allocate all that memory and initialize the lists rather often (1 big one for the outer loop, and n of them for the inner one).  If you use `xrange()` instead, you'll find it runs much quicker.

Comment: Thank you so much! @jszakmeister You really solve my problem. After using xrange(), my code runs much faster!

Comment: You're welcome!  It's the little things that end up hurting the most. :-)  Fortunately, in Python 3, `range()` always returns a generator just like `xrange()` in Python 2, so it's less of a problem there.

Comment: I should add to that use a profiler, such as [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)  can help you identify these kinds of things too.  You'd see that the range function is consuming 1.5s of time, which is a good tip-off that it's not behaving the way you would expect.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the algorythms' complexity you are right that **with your test data** both solutions perform a similar number of iterations.

Most of the time in your second solution is spent in the calls to `range`. Use `xrange` instead (or python 3 instead of python2) and both solutions will take almost the same time **with your test data**.

Answer (score 1):

This is something called algorithm analysis and your question illustrates it well. If you'd like to learn more, look up Big O.

Essentially Big O looks at orders of magnitude. In your second solution you can see that you loop from 0 to n and inside that loop you also loop from temp_j to n (on average) meaning you have a magnitude of O(N)*O(N) which is roughly O(N^2) whereas your original solution has a magnitude of O(N).

The N in big oh signifies how long the algorithm will take to run. N^2 is algorithmically a worse design (in terms of pure speed) than N.

Answer (score 1):

I'm here responding to your edit:

> Some answers mentioned O(N) of single loop and O(N^2) of nested loop. But I think there are two conditions in solution 1 (i < N and j < N), which means the worse case might be O(N^2), too.

Your first solution consists in a single `while` loop:

```
while i < len(s) and j < len(s):
    ...
```

Your second solution consists in two nested `for` loops:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(temp_j,n):
        ...
```

In the second solution, for every `i`, you check every `j`. So you enter `n*(n-temp_j)` times in that inner loop, or roughly `n^2` times.

In the first solution however, at any iteration, either `i` or `j` is incremented, meaning that after `2*len(s)` iterations, your loop will end.

Therefore, the first solution has a O(n) complexity, and the second, a O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. thanks! but I think solution 2 may not enter n*(n-temp_j) times because of the "break" statement. I mean in the real case. I have done tests in runtime, both of these two solutions enter almost the same times. You can use the test case above and run both codes.thank you very much